# Transitivity of the divisibility relationship among integers.

Tags: proof-verification, divisibility

Prove if a, b and c are integers such that a is divisible by b, and b is divisible by c, then a is divisible by c
I've recently been looking into divisibility proofs since I'm new to proofs as a whole, and have come across one particular question that is throwing me off. I'm not sure whether it's throwing me off because it's a false proof (in which case I cannot find a counter-example) or whether my method is wrong.

---

"Prove if true or disprove through counter-example: if a, b and c are integers such that a is
divisible by b, and b is divisible by c, then a is divisible by c."

My methodology involves the following...

a/b = k
b/c = z
a/c = n

Where k, z and n are all integers.

Thus...
b = a/k
c = b/z
a = czk

So...

a/c = czk/(b/z)

So...

a/c = k/z

But I've hit a wall there. Seems very messy and I doubt I'm on the right track. Would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: If $a=bn$ and $b=cm$ then $a=cmn$

Comment: I have taken the liberty to give your title a more compact shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this definition of divisibility:

> $a$ divides $b$ if and only if $b=k\cdot a$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$.

Here is an outline of what you should do:

1. Write down what it means that $a$ divides $b$. (giving you equation (i))
2. Write down what it means that $b$ divides $c$. (giving equation (ii))
3. Write down what it means that $a$ divides $c$ (which is what you want to prove)
4. Try to merge equations (i) and (ii) to get something that can be used for (3).

Comment: Thanks! Got it... since a/b if a = kb... b/c if b = nc... (where k and n are natural numbers)... a = k(nc) = knc... therefore a/c = kn for some kn is a natural number!